# de sugaring do notation

Tags: haskell, applicative, do-notation

I want to de sugar the following do notation. But im unsure whether I have got it right:

Is:

```
quote   = do
    time        <- qtime
    qcomma
    ask         <- double
    qcomma
    bid         <- double
    qcomma
    askVolume   <- double
    qcomma
    bidVolume   <- double
    endOfLine
    return $ Quote time ask bid askVolume bidVolume
```

And

```
quote   = Quote <$> (qtime <* qcomma)
                <*> (double <* qcomma)
                <*> (double <* qcomma)
                <*> (double <* qcomma)
                <*> (double <* endOfLine)
```

Equivalent to:

```
qtime >>= (\time -> qcomma) 
    >> double 
        >>= (\ ask -> qcomma)  
            >> double  
                >>= (\bid -> qcomma) 
                    >> double
                        >>= (\askVolume  -> qcomma) 
                            >> double
                                >>= (\bidVolume  -> endOfLine)
                                    return (Quote time ask bid askVolume bidVolume )
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `do` notation desugars to *nested* lambdas, because (for example) `time` is in scope for the rest of the `do` block, not just the first call to `qcomma`:

```
qtime >>= (
  \time -> qcomma
      >> double 
      >>= (\ ask -> qcomma
               >> double  
               >>= (\bid -> qcomma 
                       >> double
                       >>= (\askVolume  -> qcomma 
                                    >> double
                                    >>= (\bidVolume  -> endOfLine
                                          return (Quote time ask bid askVolume bidVolume ))))))
```

The applicative version might have the same effect, but is not desugared to anything.

Starting with GHC 8, the `do` notation *might* desugar to applicative code if (`ApplicativeDo` is turned on and) the compiler can determine that `>>=` isn't necessary and the more general `Applicative` instance has the same meaning.

Comment: It's impressive GHC would desugar to `Applicative`, but why? there is no guarantee it will perform better, is there?

Comment: Monads enforce an order of operations not required by `Applicative` code, which has implications for parallelization. Letting the compiler decide if an available Applicative instance is suitable for a `do` expression frees the programmer from unnecessarily commuting to a monad.